# MYSQL - Group BY with MAX issue

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I have the following table

```
  Date, TelephoneNumber, Type
  02/02/12, 123456, b
  04/02/12, 123456, b
  07/02/12, 123456, a
  03/02/12, 789999, a
  15/02/12, 789999, b
```

When running the following SQL

```
        select TelephoneNumber, max(Date) as datetime, Type
        from Table1
        where Date > '2012-03-25 00:00'
        group by TelephoneNumber
        order by date desc;
```

I noted that the Type does not match its related Date. For example I am getting

```
  07/02/12, 123456, b
  15/02/12, 789999, a
```

It seems that it is taking the first record in Type .... even when I sorted in the other way round. Can someone please help me how I can solve this problem? I am using MySQL

Thanks in advance.
sandro

Comment: MySQL's group-by function uses the first-encountered row to fill in a value for any non-grouped field in a result row. This is unavoidable with simple query statments like yours. See this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979034/mysql-shows-incorrect-rows-when-using-group-by

Comment: What is it exactly that you are expecting to happen. Asking a more direct question is always better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question seems to pop up quite often.

Here's my solution:

```
SELECT TelephoneNumber, Date AS datetime, Type
from ( SELECT *
       FROM Table1
       WHERE Date > '2012-03-25 00:00'
       ORDER BY Date DESC) AS h
GROUP BY TelephoneNumber
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

[Check explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801484/query-two-db-using-group-by-and-display-detail-information?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 2):

This is because, as [§11.16.3 "`GROUP BY` and `HAVING` with Hidden Columns" in the *MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) puts it:

> MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the
>           select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the
>           `GROUP BY` clause. This means that the
>           preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to
>           get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting
>           and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values
>           in each nonaggregated column not named in the `GROUP
>           BY` are the same for each group. **The server is free to
>           choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same,
>           the values chosen are indeterminate.** Furthermore, the selection
>           of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an
>           `ORDER BY` clause. Sorting of the result set
>           occurs after values have been chosen, and `ORDER
>           BY` does not affect which values the server chooses.

[emphasis mine]

Instead, you need to write something like this:

```
select t1a.TelephoneNumber, t1a.Date, t1a.Type
  from Table1 as t1a
  left
  join Table1 as t1b
    on t1b.TelephoneNumber = t1a.TelephoneNumber
   and t1b.Date > t1a.Date
 where t1a.Date > '2012-03-25 00:00'
   and t1b.TelephoneNumber IS NULL                -- i.e., the join failed
;
```

to find the record with the greatest `Date` for each value of `TelephoneNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Order is applied after grouping. The value of max(Date) has already been computed, you're not sorting it in any way. Also, what is `msisdn`? It's impossible to tell what's going on with your query because what you're actually grouping on is opaque.

Comment: that was a mispprint :) check now please